# How to get clipboard data on copy/paste events?

Tags: angularjs

How to get the clipboard data with ng-paste and ng-copy directives?

```
<input type="text" ng-paste="mymodel = 'the clipboard text??'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A crossbrowser solution is to define a $clipboard service like this:

```
function Clipboard($window) {
    this.getText = function ($event) {
        var text;
        if ($window.clipboardData) { //IE
            text = $window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        } else if ($event.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
            try {
                text = $event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            } catch (ex) {
                text = undefined;
            }
        }
        if (text) {
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
        return text;
    };
}
angular.module("ngClipboard", []).service("$clipboard", Clipboard);
```

Then injecting the service in controllers and defining a delegate method it can be used like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-paste="mymodel = getText($event)" />
```